# How to get descriptive statistics of all columns in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, data-analysis

I have a dataset with 200000 rows and 201 columns. I want to have descriptive statistics of all the variables.
I tried:
        '''train.describe()'''
But this is only giving the output for the first and last 8 variables. This there any method I can use to get the statistics for all of the columns.

Answer (score 1):

probably, some of your columns where in some  type other than numerical. Try `train.apply(pd.to_numeric)` then `train.describe()`